# Correct Version of ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, centos

I'm having issues replicating a centos 6 instance. It looks like I have 2 versions of ffmpeg on my old server:

`ffmpeg -version` gives me:

```
ffmpeg version 1.2.5
built on Jan 30 2014 19:45:47 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-decoder=png --enable-encoder=png --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib
```

but `/root/bin/ffmpeg -version` gives me:

```
ffmpeg version git-2016-05-31-971351b Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265
```

I tried using this guide https://www.ostechnix.com/install-ffmpeg-linux/ to get the newest version of ffmpeg but that gave me,

```
ffmpeg version 0.10.16
built on Aug 26 2016 13:01:36 with gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libcelt --enable-libdc1394 --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
```

Prior to using that guide the `yum install` gave me a `0.6.5` version which I guess meant my repo was ever further out of date.

How can I take the same version my old server is using, or install the latest version? The version numbers and copyright years also seem off to me. Should't `1.2.5` come after the `0.10.16` release?

(These threads lead me here, [Any downsides to always using the -movflags faststart parameter?](https://superuser.com/questions/856025/any-downsides-to-always-using-the-movflags-faststart-parameter) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419351/ffmpeg-using-movflags-faststart)

Comment: Get a git binary from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/. The `built on` date  just tells you when it was compiled - not the vintage of the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the up to date version of ffmpeg here, https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/. I used the following steps:

1. `yum remove ffmpeg` (to delete my previous version built from out of date repo)
2. `wget https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz`
3. `tar xvf ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz`
4. `mv ffmpeg-4.0.2-64bit-static/ffmpeg ffmpeg-4.0.2-64bit-static/ffprobe
   /usr/bin/`

For more detailed instructions: https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/faq/